# Laravel 5.2: Empty cookie

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, middleware

I am not able to get the result from a cookie, which I set in my custom middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    Cookie::queue('MyTestCookie', 'test', 45000);
    return $next($request);
}
```

After that I call **Cookie::get('MyTestCookie');** - the result is **[ ]**

Where I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Did you try to display the cookie via the `$value = $request->cookie('MyTestCookie');`)? See documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#cookies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer:

You can't access the cookie on the same request where you set it.

### A little explanation:

The basic workflow is that, you set a cookie, this will be attached with the response. When the response sent back to the browser, it'll be stored in the browser. Then, on the next subsequent request, the browser'll attach the cookie with the request and you can get the cookie from the request.

Regarding `Cookie::queue` method in `Laravel`, actually the `queue` method allows you to create a cookie even without having/creating a response but ultimately, the queued cookies are not attached immediately with the response because the response is created at the last moment of your script execution. So, queued cookies are stored somewhere (CookieJar handles it) and when the framework sends the response, it checks if there is any queued cookies available and if there are any then the framework attaches each queued cookies using a loop within the `AddQueuedCookiesToResponse` middleware, which is:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    foreach ($this->cookies->getQueuedCookies() as $cookie) {
        $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

This is an `after` middleware which runs (the handle method is called) after the request has been processed. So, you can't access the cookie on the same request where you set it.

Answer (score 0):

@The Alpha - thank you for this answer - it helped me to understand the workflow.

My mistake is that I didn't clarified where exactly I try to get the value of the cookie. I will explain the workflow of the project:

### Workflow of my project

On initial website load I create a cookie with default data for every visitor. After the user is logged into the system successfully - I am getting his default cookie and update it depending on his actions.

User requests the website (I am creating a cookie and queue it to the response) -> The user has the website homepage and attempts to log into the system (he makes new request with the cookie, which I send him with the homepage) -> the application takes the request with the cookie and verifies that the user credentials are correct - he receives response with the User view.

The problem is that I am not able to get the cookie value before I send the response with the User view, but the cookie exists.